# Tensorflow initial_weights what mean?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Why we have to init weight in model predict? I can't understand.

You can refer : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#checkpoint_the_initial_weights

```
initial_weights = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(), 'initial_weights')

model.save_weights(initial_weights)
```

Comment: Weight initialization is used to define the initial values for the parameters in a neural network model prior to training the models on a dataset. Its a really important part as setting the wrong value could cause the model to not converge at all.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial appears to be referring to unbalanced data. You do not need to provide initial weights if you don't want to in Tensorflow's predict command. See [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) describing potential inputs to the command.

Comment: thanks your answer. However, Can you explore about model with init weight and without ?

Answer (score 0):

Deep learning using Gradient Descent and its variant to find optimal weights. If you don't init weights, it may take a long time to converge or even can't converge.